# HTML mail get cropped in Gmail

Tags: html, email, gmail

I am sending a news letter, which sometimes gets long.

For some reason, if the mail is exceptionally long it gets cropped in Gmail's web application. However, when i view the same mail on my iPhone or Outlook everything seems to work fine.

The mail itself is HTML and I am 100% sure that Gmail doesn't crop the original mail since I've also forwarded it from my Gmail account to a different mail account and managed to get the entire mail in the other web application.

I am running Vista 64bit and I tried to view the mail in FF, Chrome & IE but got the same result on all of them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was a length limitation on Gmail's end, the HTML itself was formatted into a single line, this is what caused the view problem. To solve it, I've cut down the HTML into several lines and everything started to work great.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing the HTML and the result in an email, the only suggestion I can make is that you check to make sure all your CSS is inline and that you are using absolutely no JavaScript.  The rules of web development and separation of content and presentation don't apply to emails, unfortunately.

However, check to make sure you are emailing a full, HTML document with a doctype, head, and body.

You could also use a debugger like Firebug to inspect the document to determine if there are any CSS tweaks you can make to render the document, such as perhaps using a fixed height, max-height, margin, or padding rule.

Comment: Thanks jmort253, I am not using a CSS, the style is applied to the HTML elements directly. It doesn't seem like a formatting or a HTML error issue since the mail get cropped by size with no regards to the content. I have tried adding the proper surrounding HTML document tags but it didn't help either. When I use Firebug I can clearly see that the HTML got cropped in the middle and it is not a display error. However, when I use Gmail's "Show Original" email link I can see that the entire original mail is in tact.

Comment: Does the HTML document validate by itself?  Is it considered valid by W3C standards?

Comment: I just modified it to match W3C's standard (loose.dtd) but it doesn't make a difference. I also noticed that the same thing is happening to other providers from which i long emails in GMail. So I am not quite sure it is a problem on my end. Yet, I was wondering whether there is anything I can do to fix it.